# Dictionarys combine python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to combine 2 dictionarys. Search a bit but couldn't find it yet. Because I don't really know how it's called.
But this are the two dictonary's I got:

Number 1:

`Counter({'gag': 19, 'ccc': 15, 'cct': 15, 'ctg': 15, 'tcc': 13, 'aag': 13, 'atg': 12, 'cag': 12, 'gcc': 12, 'gaa': 11, 'gat': 11, 'aac': 10, 'gtg': 10, 'cca': 9, 'gac': 9, 'acc': 9, 'ggg': 9, 'agc': 8, 'cgc': 8, 'tct': 7, 'aaa': 7, 'ttc': 7, 'atc': 7, 'cac': 7, 'aca': 7, 'gct': 6, 'ccg': 6, 'ttg': 6, 'ggc': 6, 'tgc': 6, 'tca': 6, 'tac': 6, 'gca': 5, 'ctc': 5, 'ggt': 5, 'cat': 5, 'gtt': 5, 'cgt': 5, 'ttt': 4, 'tgt': 4, 'act': 4, 'aat': 4, 'tgg': 4, 'cga': 4, 'agt': 4, 'tat': 3, 'gga': 3, 'cgg': 3, 'cta': 3, 'agg': 3, 'caa': 3, 'ctt': 3, 'gtc': 3, 'aga': 3, 'acg': 2, 'gcg': 1, 'att': 1, 'tga': 1})`

And number 2:

`{'Phe': ['ttt', 'ttc'], 'Stop': ['tag', 'tga', 'taa'], 'Pro': ['cct', 'ccc', 'cca', 'ccg'], 'Trp': ['tgg'], 'Met': ['atg'], 'Lys': ['aaa', 'aag'], 'His': ['cat', 'cac'], 'Asp': ['gat', 'gac'], 'Start': ['atg', 'ctg', 'ttg', 'gtg', 'att'], 'Thr': ['act', 'acc', 'aca', 'acg'], 'Tyr': ['tat', 'tac'], 'Glu': ['gaa', 'cag'], 'Asn': ['aat', 'aac'], 'Val': ['gtt', 'gtc', 'gta', 'gtg'], 'Ser': ['tct', 'tcc', 'tca', 'tcg', 'agt', 'agc'], 'Cys': ['tgt', 'tgc'], 'Ile': ['att', 'atc', 'ata'], 'Leu': ['tta', 'ttg', 'ctt', 'ctc', 'cta', 'ctg'], 'Gly': ['ggt', 'ggc', 'gga', 'ggg'], 'Gln': ['caa', 'cag'], 'Arg': ['cgt', 'cgc', 'cga', 'cgg', 'aga', 'agg'], 'Ala': ['gct', 'gcc', 'gca', 'gcg']}`

Now I want to count how much from every amino acid (dic 2 with phe, pro, trp, etc.) are made. So for example:
Phe has 'ttt' and 'ttc' I want to count how many phe's are in the 1st dic. But I don't know how, can anyone help?

Comment: Does that mean `number1['ttt'] + number1['ttc']`?

Comment: Yes, and than for all dict items in dict 2

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the sums using a default value of `0` for those not found using this line:

```
sums = {k: sum(counter.get(tv, 0) for tv in v) for k, v in dictionary.items()}
```

Assuming `counter` is the first mapping and `dictionary` is the second mapping.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new dictionary for the sums:

```
total = {k: sum(number1.get(subk, 0) for subk in v) for k, v in number2.items()}
```

Comment: total = {k: sum(aa[subk] for subk in v) for k, v in aa3.iteritems()}
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: This is also not safe in case the value is not found in `counter`. Either change `counter` to a `defaultdict` or use `dict.get` with a default value 0.

Comment: @RubenOldenkamp: That is because you are using Python3.  In Python3, you need to use `.items().`  I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking for something like this.

```
def get_count(name):
    count = 0
    for item in number2[name]:
        count += number1.get(item) or 0
    return count

get_count('Phe')
```